# How do I search for a string and then insert a newline at the beginning, for all lines in file?

Tags: vim, newlines, vimrc, macro

I want to search an entire file for the string `---` when it appears at the beginning of a line. I then want to insert a newline before each instance of that string.

In my `.vimrc` file, I added this command:

```
let @p=":1,$s/^---/^M---/"
```

When I execute it, it does not insert the newline character. Instead it ignores everything from the `^M` on, so it replaces the `---` with a null string, removing the 3 dashes from each line that contains them at the beginning.

What is wrong with my @p command? I doesn't seem to recognize the `^M` character. Is this not allowed in a search and replace command? I can do this manually, by the way, by simply typing the exact same command at the `:` prompt at the bottom of the file.

I also tried:

```
let @p=":1,$s/^---/^M^[---/"
```

(added an escape after the newline) - this gave me the exact same result. Looks like it's ignoring the escape along with the rest of the replace section.

Can someone tell me the correct way to do this? I do want to keep these commands in the vimrc file, because I edit a lot of files that have the same set of commands (and involve several macros, all of which work fine except this one), so I don't want to recreate the same macros every time I open a new file.

Thank you!

Comment: DO you insist to be `vi` script? Or you will accept `awk`, `sed`....?

Comment: How did you add the `^M`? Ctrl-V Ctrl-M?

Comment: Linux newline is not Control-M (carriage return) but rather Control-J (line feed).

Comment: @RomeoNinov This generates a `vi` macro, so it seems this is needed during editing.

Comment: @SottoVoce But a carriage return is the character that is generated when hitting the return key, and that's what matters here. Try to enter `:%s/-/^M/g` in `vim` and see all dashes get replaced by line breaks.

Comment: @Philippos, this is your speculation. And it is not optimal to do this in editor, especially if you have more than 10-20 such lines.

Comment: @RomeoNinov What does the number of lines matter? Using `1,$` or `%` it will process all lines. And if you are editing, using an external command is usually not the best option. The OP wrote it's needed as a macro.

Comment: @muru  You can get the ^M by typing either Ctrl-v Ctrl-m or Ctrl-v and then hit Return.

Comment: @Bastette yes, I'm aware. I'm asking how *you* did it. For all we know you could have just written a caret and an M.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the characters in a script will act as if they were typed. So on `^M` a carriage return will be executed. So you need to write

```
let @p=":1,$s/^---/^V^M---/^M"
```

because this is what you would type when manually recording the macro. Of course, to write this, you need to type <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, then <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, then <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> and finally <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>.

Also note that you need a final `^M` at the end to really execute the command, not just place it in the buffer.

And btw you can simplify `1,$` to `%` and use `&` instead of repeating the pattern, so you can write

```
let @p=":%s/^---/^V^M&/^M"
```

Comment: If that was the problem then it's probably better to use `\r` instead. In the replacement of `:s`, Vim takes `\r` to mean newline and `\n` to mean the null character

Comment: If you use `\r` in a script, the same thing will happen, I'm afraid. I never found a way to solve the problem other than I wrote it. If you have something else proved to work, please let us know.

Comment: `let @p=":1,$s/^---/\\r---/\n"` should work In double-quoted strings, the `\` for `\r` will need to be escaped.

Comment: @Philippos Thank you, that solved the problem!

I'm curious why you need the extra ^M at the very end. You said it was to execute the command and not just place it in the buffer. I have a lot of other macros, and all I do is type @# (where # is the letter used to access the macro in the register) and most of my macros just execute, without a ^M at the end of the string. I'm wondering why this one is different.

Comment: @Bastette because this one leaves normal mode to go to command line mode, and types out a command. But that command needs to be executed, otherwise it'd just be setting there with the command filled in. So the final ^M or (`\n` in my variant) acts as the Enter key executing that command.

Comment: @muru That's interesting. Does this apply to other commands as well? Some macros automatically execute when I enter @# (letter), while others just sit at the : prompt at the bottom. I have a command:

let @l=":/=$"

When I enter @l, the search command:

/=$

Comment: I suppose this applies to all `:` commands, because you need to enter the return key at the end of the command. For a macro out of editor commands like a word swap `let @s="dEBP"` you don't need it, because you also wouldn't press the return key on recording the macro.